# Proof that n-Dimensional Rotations Leave A (n-2) Subspace Fixed

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, rotations

Looking at many of the questions on this site and literature, there are many references made to the fact that rotations in ${\Bbb R}^n$ leave a $(n-2)$ dimensional subspace fixed.

I have looked for a proof of this statement, and couldn't find any.

This is as close as I got:

> Let $R$ be a rotation in ${\Bbb R}^n$. If for some non-zero vector $v$, $Rv = v$, then there exists $(n-3)$ vectors $w_1, w_2, ...$ mutually orthogonal to themselves and $v$, such that $Rw=w$

Based on the question [Rotation in 4D?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402362/rotation-in-4d)
But I failed to find a proof as I couldn't prove that the Eigenspace corresponding to the '$+1$' eigenvectors was $n-2$ dimensional.

Comment: What’s your definition of a rotation?

Comment: In 4D rotation it can happen that there is no fixed vectors.

Comment: @amd a rotation is an orthogonal matrix R with det(R) = 1

Comment: @Widawensen how is this?

Comment: @AdamKelly See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_in_4-dimensional_Euclidean_space   for details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposition is false. Take, for example, $R=\operatorname{diag}(-1,-1,-1,-1,1,\dots)$. Its determinant is $1$, so it’s a rotation, but the eigenspace of $1$ is obviously $(n-4)$-dimensional. (If you don’t like using what seems like a reflection, replace the first four rows with a pair of Givens rotations.) Indeed, a rotation in $\mathbb R^{2m}$ for $m\ge2$ need not have any non-trivial fixed points at all: a simple example is $-I$.

Now, you could define a *simple* rotation, similar to a [Givens rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation), that only has a single plane of rotation, but then the proposition pretty much *is* the definition of the rotation itself.

There are some interesting things that one can say about planes of rotation and their relationship to the eigenvalues of a rotation, though. [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_of_rotation) is a pretty good gloss on the subject.