# Why is the group of rotations in $\mathbb{R}^n$ not $n$-dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, lie-groups

I have a rather basic mis-understanding about Lie groups and Lie algebras. Consider the Lie group $SO(N)$ for $N>3$ of rotations on $\mathbb{R}^N$. On the one hand this Lie group has dimension $N(N-1)/2$, since every $SO(N)$ element can be parametrized as $e^{X}$, where $X$ is an anti-symmetric matrix with $N(N-1)/2$ free parameters.

On the other hand, $\mathbb{R}^N$ has $N$ cardinal axes. Can I not express every rotation in $\mathbb{R}^N$ as products of rotations about the axes, implying that $SO(N)$ has dimension $N$? Where do the additional degrees of freedom come from? A follow up related question is: each Lie algebra generator $X(i,j)$, for $1 \leq i < j \leq N$ generates a one-parameter group of rotations $O(\theta) = e^{\theta X_{ij}}$. Is there a simple geometric explanation for which axis this rotation is about?

Comment: Well, what would it even *mean* to rotate about an axis in (say) $\mathbb{R}^4$? What would be the matrix for that? You should think about rotations in two-dimensional subspaces instead.

Comment: Maybe look at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1402376/27978 It is worthwhile noting that $\binom{n}{2} = {n (n-1) \over 2}$.

Comment: (That is, you need to consider rotating in 2d planes rather than about axes.)

Comment: To be concrete, write down an element of $SO(4)$ that is not rotation about any axis. In particular, $1$ will not be an eigenvalue of this linear map.

Comment: Rotations can be characterized by points on a sphere which is one dimension lower already and some of those will be redundant. You should expect some loss of dimensionality.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Define rotation?

Comment: @TedShifrin I define a rotation as an element of the special orthogonal group. They're rotations so you're allowed to define them circularly.

Comment: Bit they aren’t necessarily rotations about an axis in dimension $>3$, so your comment seems misleading and wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly note that already in just 2 dimensions this doesn't make sense. $SO(2)$ represents rotations in the plane and is 1 dimensional. So the naive assumption should be that we have $\frac{N}{2}$ ($\frac{N-1}{2}$  if $N$ is odd) dimensions for $SO(N)$ by splitting into orthogonal 2-dimensional subspaces . The problem being that products of these simple rotations don't generate all possible elements of $SO(N)$. Indeed they generate exactly a Cartan subgroup.

The next naive guess is that we shouldn't have made the 2-dimensional subspaces orthogonal and worked with all subspaces or at least all subspaces we get from a fixed orthonormal basis. But the number of those is exactly $N$ choose $2$ or $\frac{N(N-1)}{2}$ which is the correct answer. Obviously I haven't shown that there is no redundancy there but this is the right idea.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody seems to have mentioned $\mathbb R=\mathbb R^1$ yet, and yet it would seem to be a good answer to the question: the group of rotations of $\mathbb R^1$ is $0$-dimensional.  Namely, it consists of only two "rotations": the identity map and the antipodal map $x\mapsto -x$.

Comment: I'd argue the second of those is a reflection and that $O(1)$ comprises two elements while $SO(1)$ is just the identity.

Comment: @Callum, very true.

Comment: @Callum, this does not change the dimension of the group :-)